# Max's Crash and Gs

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

I was watching the British GP recently. Max Verstappen, who was initially leading the race, crashed out. Thankfully, he is all well, but he suffered a 51G shunt. I have been wanting to know how these values are measured and also these G values involved in crashes, what are they? I mean what forces do they represent?

[Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIKel6jVD3Q) of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

A "g" or "g-force"$^1$ is a measure of change in speed, or acceleration. We measure the value of a $g$ as the speed an object gets if it is in free-fall on the earths surface for 1 second. This happens to be $9.8 \;\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$ or $9.8$ meters per second per second, meaning as a numerical figure, $1g=9.8$.

So an object falling for $t$ seconds will have a speed of $$v=9.8\times t$$

In car crashes, we use this as a way to gauge the seriousness of such an impact, using the acceleration felt by the human body. The higher this value, the more likely that injury, or worse, can result.

The $51g$ shunt you mentioned, is equivalent to  an acceleration  of $$51 \times 9.8 \approx 510 \;\text{m}\,\text{s}^{-2}$$

I'm surprised the driver sustained no injuries since according to the [National Highway and Transport and Safety Administration](https://www.nhtsa.gov/) in America:

> The NHTSA standard for a sudden impact acceleration on a human that would cause severe injury or death is 75 g's for a "50th percentile male", 65 g's for a "50th percentile female", and 50 g's for a "50th percentile child". These figures assume the human is taking the impact on the chest/stomach, the back, sides or the head. The average value is about 65 g's.

$^1$The term "g-*force*" is not actually correct since it is a measure of acceleration and not force.